# Is it possible to change control visibility from another control trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have this style and trigger for a IsMouseOver property of a combobox (turned into a menu). I would like to change the visibility of another object when this trigger fires on (when the mouse is over the item) is this possible? Currently I'm just setting up the Foreground when this happens but I think they must be a way.

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,20,5" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HeaderMenuButtonColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HeaderMenuButtonHoverColorBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the logic by putting a trigger on the affected control, however you need a way to target the control that this style is applied to.

e.g.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=ThatMenuItem}" ...>
```

Using the triggers and actions from `Interactivity` (Blend SDK) you could affect other controls, but you would need to revert your actions as those are imperative (i.e. a trigger on `false` as well, doing what is necessary to revert what was done in the `true`-trigger).

Comment: HB The menu is being dinamically created (using databind to a viewmodel) so I can't know the element name. Is it possible to do this other way?

Comment: A little trickier to do (I'm not proficient with WPF) but could done what I want to. Thanks for your help, +1 for the god will :)

Comment: Glad you could work it out on your own :) (Actually i am surprised now that i think about it, `Interactivity` isn't really meant for `Styles`, so good job on however you did it)